# If $X(t)$ is a Brownian motion, show that $-X(t)$ is also a Brownian motion

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

> Let $X(t), t \geq 0$ be a Brownian motion process with drift parameter
>   $\mu$ and variance parameter $\sigma^{2}$ for which $X(0) = 0$. Show
>   that $-X(t), t \geq 0$ is a Brownian motion process with drift
>   parameter -$\mu$ and parameter $\sigma^{2}$

I'm not too sure about how to approach this question. I think that we need to show that $-X(t)$ satisfies the definition of a Brownian motion, namely that $X(0)$ is a given constant, and for all positive $y$ and $t$, $X(t + y) - X(y)$ is independent of the process up to time $y$ and has a normal distribution with parameters $t\mu$ and $t\sigma^{2}$.

Comment: Which one of the properties you have difficulty with ?

Comment: For the first property, I think I can just say $-X(0)= -0 = 0$, so this property is satisfied. Is this correct? I'm struggling with the second property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first point, you are indeed right, since Brownian motion with drift starts at $0$ with probability $1$.

As for the other properties, note that if we let $Y(t)=-X(t)$, then you have that

$$Y(t) - Y(s) = X(s)-X(t) = -(X(t)-X(s)) \quad \text{for} \quad t>s$$

Using the properties of Brownian motion (distribution, independence, stationarity of increments) and the fact that the transformation applied is **linear**, can you see what the distribution of this last quantity is?

Comment: So, how can I show that the distribution is normal with drift parameter $-\mu$ and $\sigma^{2}$?

Comment: You do know the distribution of $X(t) -X(s)$, because of the definition of Brownian motion with drift. What happens when you apply a linear transformation to this distribution?

Comment: I am not familiar with linear transformations. I know that $X(t) - X(s)$ follows normal distribution with mean $(t - s)\mu$ and variance $(t - s)\sigma^{2}$

Comment: In other words: if $Z$ is normal with mean $a$ and variance $b$ ($Z\sim\mathcal{N}(a,b)$) what is the distribution of $-Z$?

Comment: I know the answer is $-a$ and $b$, but don't I need to show that?

Comment: Since you already know that $Z:= X(t) - X(s)$ is normal with mean $a:= (t-s)\mu$ and variance $(t-s)\sigma^2$, you can apply that result about $-Z$. Or do you mean you think you have to show that result about $-Z$? I don't think you would be expected to show that here -- it is a very basic fact about normal distributions and would be assumed knowledge at this point since you are dealing with more complicated things now (like Brownian motion).

Comment: @stackofhay42 it is a more general property of random variables, not restricted to normal distributions